# How can I make my 2x1 table product description appear vertically on mobile? be mobile responsive

Tags: html

I want to show my product description like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: <table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px; width: 60%;">
<p><strong>Natural Poplar Wood</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Bring a refreshing rustic charm to your home, office, or party decor.... </p>
</td>
<td><img style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508919801845-fc2ae1bc2a28?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aW1nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>demo</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .list-item{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .list-item-img{
        width: 25%;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .list-item-img img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .list-item-c{
        width: 75%;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    .list-item-about{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .list-item-title{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 650;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px){
    .list-item-c{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .list-item-img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .list-item{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="main-div">
        <div class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508919801845-fc2ae1bc2a28?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aW1nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
            </div>
            <div class="list-item-c">
                <p class="list-item-title">your title</p>
                <p class="list-item-about">about item...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method using css grid

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1626677381009-ac05aecb0b7d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80"></div>
  <div class="item2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
 
</div>

<style>


@media (min-width: 56.25em){

.container {
 display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
grid-auto-flow: column;

}


.item2 {
  grid-column-start:2;
  grid-column-end:3;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column-start:1;
 grid-column-end: 1;
}
}

img{
  width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Here's my code:
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px; width: 60%;">
<p><strong>Natural Poplar Wood</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Bring refreshing rustic .......</p>
</td>
<td><img style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508919801845-fc2ae1bc2a28?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aW1nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>